# Get Windows to print the document name on all printed PDF files

Tags: windows, pdf, printing

I'm looking for a way (using any program needed) to have the file name printed on every PDF document printed from the windows context menu.

I checked Acrobat Reader but that one doesn't have an option for this. Any solution that doesn't require interaction (documents are printed in batch) will do.

Comment: So you want a cover sheet/front page or to (temporarily) **edit** the pdf on the fly to contain the actual file name - where? On every page, in the header/footer/watermark/stamp?

Answer (score 0):

After searching for another hour I found something that suits my needs and might be helpful to others.  A neat little app (free!) that stamps the document name on one or more PDF(s) by dragging it into the dialog...  works perfectly!

[It's called PDF filename labeler and can be downloaded here](http://www.saintjohnny.com/)